# Configure Finder dock icon to open another directory

Tags: finder

By default, the Finder dock icon opens `All My Files` directory.

How do I configure it to open a directory specified by me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Finder open, press Cmd+` to open the Finder Preferences window.

In this window you'll see a drop down list that lets you select where new Finder window open to when you open them.

[image]

There are some suggestions made when you click on the drop down list or you can choose `Other...` and pick any folder you like.

[image]